# How do I print out a value in assembly language

Tags: variables, assembly, printing, integer, lc3

I'm trying to print int "1" from a variable in LC3

I have:

> COUNTER .FILL #1
>
> LD R1, COUNTER
>
> PUTC

but this prints "'0" (apostrophe zero)

Comment: I have no experience with LC-3, but here are a few things you may want to try: (1) use `R0` instead of `R1`; (2) try `x31` (the ASCII code of digit '1') instead of `#1`.

Answer (score 1):

To print in lc3, there are two easy system routines available to use.

1) PUTS - "Write a string of ASCII characters to the console display. The characters are contained
in consecutive memory locations, one character per memory location, starting with the address specified in R0. Writing terminates with the occurrence of x0000 in a memory location"*

2) OUT - "Write a character in R0[7:0] to the console display."*

Since you're just printing one character, you can use the OUT routine like so:

```
COUNTER .FILL #1
LD R0, COUNTER
OUT
```

Note the register is R0, not R1 like you had.

You could also use PUTS here, but PUTS will print until it finds x0000 in the next memory location.  So for one character, using OUT is safer.

*See http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/dl/free/0072467509/104653/PattPatelAppA.pdf